# is possible to build applications directly into gmail using google applications (google.com/a)?

Tags: crm, google-apps, salesforce

We are looking for a CRM web application and so far salesforce.com/force.com seems the only one which allows you to build applications directly on their platform. However I was wondering if gmail/google applications offer the same freedom on their platform .

So far we found a firefox extension being "exactly" what we are looking for. You may take a look at  http://rapportive.com/. As you can see the contact details appear directly in the gmail interface.
    The only issue is that the extension may become unstable if gmail changes its interface or slower if we want to more complex features so I would like to know if it's possible to build the features directly on the gmail platform . 
  Basically we would like to "upgrade" the gmail application with additional features (e.g automatically reply based on the email content, contact details view as in the rapportive.com extension etc .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Gmail contextual gadget](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/gadgets/contextual/)?

I haven't tried it myself. But it looks like what you described.

Comment: :) Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can build applications on Salesforce/Force.com and integrate them directly within GMail. Look here for example: http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=77+14864804227734519682

I work as a technical lead for cloud development at the Daily Telegraph and I'd highly recommend using Salesforce/Force.com for any CRM requirements. Everything else is still quite a ways behind.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at Streak http://www.streak.com/ and their integration with GMail looks pretty impressive. I was wondering how they can do such things, but now I noticed that they require you to install a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides you with [Google AppEngine](http://appengine.google.com/), which is a plattform where you can develop your app using python or java.

Using AppEngine you can authenticate over gmail or (better) your current domain registering it with Google Apps.

GMail isn't a plattform, is an e-mail service and you can't build apps there.

Comment: Seems like what he wants is a Google Labs style extension.  Is there anyway for non-Google folk to submit to Google Labs in Gmail?  I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question. Do you want a CRM application which integrates well with GMAIL/google apps OR do you want to build CRM applications on GMAIL/Google Apps?

I am assuming the former since I don't know how to achieve the latter. If you are looking for a CRM application which integrates well with Google Apps, GMAIL etc then you should definitely look at Salesforce.com. The Force.com platform is unrivalled in the enterprise cloud computing space. But be aware it is going to cost you a lot if your requirements increase. And I'd also argue that the initial learning curve is a bit steep. But once you get used to the platform you'll productivity will rise exponentially.

And like I said it can be integrated (though the path is not smooth) with other cloud services like AWS, Google etc.